# Ubuntu 17.10 and Citrix Receiver: Partial Keyboard Capture

Tags: ubuntu, citrix-receiver

I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10, which came with the GNOME desktop environment.  Overall, I have been pleased, but one thing that has been driving me crazy is the loss of "complete" keyboard capture in a remote session with the Citrix receiver.  Before the upgrade, I could use keyboard shortcuts and largely avoid the mouse, switching back to the host when needed with ALT+F2.  Now, even ALT+TAB doesn't work.  (It switches me back to applications in the host Ubuntu desktop.)

To be clear, I can still type and whatnot in the client session, but hotkeys no longer work.  I have tried adjusting the All Regions parameter in the Citrix .ini file, but to no avail.  Any thoughts on how to resolve this would be amazing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Ubuntu I usually don't bother to exit apps, you may try to use short cut to move around the workplace by holding + and arrow up or down.

Comment: i meant holding alt + ctrl, then arrow up or down to change the workplace

Comment: This is a good suggestion (which I will use), but I don't think it solves the issue of ALT+TAB within the remote session...

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this is a Citrix verison issue.  I just reinstalled Citrix 13.4, and all is right with the world again.  Newer versions have change this feature for some reason.